# Chernobyl catastrophy

Tags: nuclear-physics, history, nuclear-engineering, explosions

Reducing the power produces xenon that lowers the speed of nuclear reactions even more.Did the increasing of power by expelling the control rods trying to force the xenon to undergo fission had consequence that the core of the reactor exponentially increased temperature of the water steam that slowed down the neutrons which in that case became highly more reactive and in one minute of no coolant flow through the core produced that terrible explossion?

Comment: Re, "...trying to force the xenon to undergo fission..." Xenon doesn't do that. The problem, stated simply, was, the Xenon poisoning--the result of a brief, planned shutdown--made the reactor slow to restart. The control-room operators were poorly trained, and they did not understand why it was slow to restart, so they defeated safeties, and they pulled the control rods out farther than they ever should have been pulled in an attempt to make it start up faster. Once the chain reaction finally got going, it went *MUCH* faster...

Comment: Right,After neutron absorbtion the Xenon just  become isothope that don't absorb neutrons so don't act as a nuclear reaction poison anymore but lot of neutrons are lost for further reactions with radioactive elements.Sorry for mistake.